# How to make AWS Lambda open a pull request on Github with updates for files already existing on a repository?

Tags: git, github, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

1. Lambda calls an API service to fetch the latest list of top-secret codenames. *Don't worry, it's not really secrets, no security concerns here. Just play along.*
2. Lambda stores the codenames, in a file called `secret-codenames.json`, in an S3 bucket.
3. A Github repo has an outdated list of codenames at `/restricted/secret-codenames.json` that needs to be updated.

Specifically, a Pull Request needs to be opened with the changes so that the list of codenames can be reviewed by a human agent before being merged to master.

**How can I do this using the Lambda function?**

Can I use Github API to achieve this? I read the documentation but I am not sure how.

Comment: if the github repo is private you will need to establish some mechanism for authentication and authorisation, but in either case the github API should work

Answer (score 0):

What i believe is if `secret-codenames.json` contains secrets it should not b maintain with `git` it should be sync directly with the Server `EC2` & `S3`

Comment: Updated question. Sorry for the confusion. It's not really secrets - I was making up a use-case similar to the architecture of the project I am working on.